# Inaccessible Boot Device after Macrium Clone setting up W10/W11 dual boot

Tags: boot, clone, macrium

Gigabyte X570 Pro Wi-Fi with 2xM.2 NVMe slots, 5800X processor

Urgent woes trying to set up dual-boot W10/W11.

1. With W10 installed on Samsung Evo M.2 NVMe 2TB in Mobo Slot 2, I created disk image with Macrium Reflect.  If I tried to move this HDD to Slot 1, I would always get Inaccessible Boot Device.  It was itself a clone that apparently didn't like to be moved slots.  This install has always been on NVMe drives, and partitions on both drives in this discussion are GPT.  Install has never lived on a SATA drive or MBR partition.
2. Moved Samsung to Slot 1 where I want it so it won't be blasted by my NVIDIA RTX 2070 Super, formatted it, installed W11 clean.  That install is fine, but there's a TON of stuff on the W10 install I need for work.
3. Inserted WD Black 512GB M.2 NVMe into Mobo Slot 2, and restored image from Step 1 to it, while booted in W11, after downloading latest version of Macrium Reflect.  I had <512GB of actual data in Windows Partition in the Image so it worked (see images below)
4. Switch boot order in BIOS to Black in Slot 2 (on latest BIOS BTW), go to boot up ... Inaccessible Boot Device. Can't access my work data.

Some screenshots:

[image: scrot1]

[image: scrot2]

At the moment I'm booted to Disk 2 (Samsung), see attached image of Disk Management tool) in W11, disk in M2 slot 1.  If I try to boot to Black (Disc 3) in Slot 2 where the Samsung was when I made the image I get the BSOD/restart.

If I set CSM to Disabled in BIOS, instead of Inaccessible Device I get this trying to boot to W10 copy.

[image: scrot3]

Comment: This is hard to follow. Please edit your question and focus, focus, focus on clarity, clearly stating the issue, what you have tried, and your specific question. Try to remove colloquialisms to help aid in general understanding.

Comment: I edited the question trying to clarify it. I removed some extra fluff which served no purpose. Please review the question, and if I accidentally removed something absolutely relevant or made a mistake (for example I've no clue what you mean with "scorching the earth") please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1773592/edit) the question to correct. On the same go, as @music2myear says, add a specific question. Do you want to 1) get access to your work data 2) get the dual boot working 3) something else? I'd do 1) first to get the important data backed up before anything else.

Comment: Thanks Peregrino, those edits are fine, except it's a Samsung Evo drive.  Scorching the earth means formatting, you guessed correctly there.  I do still have backup image of the drive and can access the file structure fine using Macrium software.  I want the dual boot to work i.e. I need the Windows 10 install I copied before starting to boot up.